# How to create a search engine, without any starting URL

Tags: search, scrapy, web-crawler

I am learning scrapy to create a search engine. As per my understanding if I want to create a search engine than the first thing I need to do would be to crawl the Internet and create cache it to my servers. Now in order to crawl I need a URL through which I will go to the next, next and so on.
But what if I don't have a starting URL and I want to search for what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/113456/100189) I found that [You can't hide your IP address on the internet. They aren't secret.](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/113458/100189)

I wrote a script and loop through IP addresses, and found website names to pass to Scrapy. That's what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a starting URL, an idea might be to **choose one**. To me it sounds like you're rather lost.

To scrape content you need to make HTTP requests to other websites, you can't make HTTP requests to other websites if you don't have a URL.

It's like trying to map every road that is located around you in the physical world. If you don't specify a starting point, what can you expect?

Comment: Yes right. But what if there is some road which is not mapped to the bigger ones? What I am thinking is to reach out to those roads. I don't know whether it is possible or not that's why I put it here.

Comment: Say there's a 1 in a 100 chance that the one you chose leads to a dead end... just choose a collection of URLs to mitigate that risk by decreasing that probability.  If I were you I'd put all those concerns aside and get a proof of concept working first

Comment: This would be the last option. Well so can I conclude that what I want is not possible?

Comment: What type of websites have a collection of other websites URLs?

Comment: "It's like trying to map every road that is located around you in the physical world. If you don't specify a starting point, what can you expect?"

A satellite, that won't require a starting road to create a map :)

Comment: May be those who has already crawled a lot of data from other websites.

Comment: `Link directories`... [DMOZ](https://www.dmoz.org/) is a popular one. As for the satellite comment... Even a satellite needs to be pointed somewhere to look...